# Getting error message while running this basic calculator

Tags: java, syntax, calculator

I'm new to Java (only been doing it for about 3 days in reality).. I have basic knowledge of Python, and decided to learn Java. I made my first calculator program in Java today, and used the same setup for the program as I have in a program in Python. The thing is, I'm getting an error message everytime i run it, though, specifically when it asks what sign i want to use on line 16. i know this is so basic, and im sure my problem is so stupid, but im only getting used to the syntax and stuff, so i'd like to know what im doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Experiment {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            double num1, num2, ans = 0;
            String sign;
            Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
            num1 = num.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("+, -, x or /? ");
            sign = num.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
            num2 = num.nextDouble();

            if(sign == "+"){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print("+");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(num1 + num2);
           }
           if(sign == "-"){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(num1 - num2);
           }
           if(sign == "x"){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print("x");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(num1 * num2);
           }
           if(sign == "/"){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print("/");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(num1 + num2);
           } else {
                System.out.print("That is not a valid input");
           }

           }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:
on line 13 you want

```
sign = num.next();
```

In the `if` blocks, you want to use the equals method on the string, not the equals operator, i.e., you want `sign.equals("+")` not `sign == "+"`
Those resolve to different values as you will see.

Furthermore, in your particular set of `if` statements, you want to start with `if` and then the next 3 if blocks should be `else if`

This is because the final `else` statement will always trigger unless `sign.equals("/")` resolves to true.  That final `else` statement is only related to the `if` right above it, and not the other `if` statements.

Comment: Aaah i see that now! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class Experiment {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            double num1, num2, ans = 0;
            String sign;
            Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
            num1 = num.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter +, -, x or /: ");
            sign = num.next();

            System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
            num2 = num.nextDouble();

            if(sign.equals("+")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" + ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" = ");
                System.out.print(num1 + num2);
           }
           else if(sign.equals("-")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" - ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" = ");
                System.out.print(num1 - num2);
           }
           else if(sign.equals("x")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" x ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" = ");
                System.out.print(num1 * num2);
           }
           else if(sign.equals("/")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" / ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" = ");
                if (num2 != 0.0)
                    System.out.print(num1 / num2);
                else
                    System.out.print("Cannot divide by 0");
           } else {
                System.out.print("That is not a valid input");
           }

     }    
}
```

Here after entering first number, user will hit enter, so your sign = `num.nextLine()` will read that enter, hence you have to use `num.next()`. Your all condition should be in `if...else if...else` and to compare strings you should use `sign.equals("+")`